# How do you track web service consumer dependencies in a SOA?

Tags: web-services, dependencies, soa, dependency-management

This question is in the context of service versionning.  How do you track the services and their versions that a consumer is calling?  What tools are there to help?

I believe that authorization controls could aid in tracking services, but that does not necessarily address the specific service version and other integration points, such as operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution providing service registry + service governance capabilities in an SOA is an ideal fit. For example, a service registry would be able to keep track of services (including multiple versions). A service governance solution would allow you to maintain relationships between services (including service versions) and consumers.

You are correct that typical authorization controls wouldn't be effective, but if you had a policy enforcement point that interacts with a service governance solution (which has the capacity to enforce policies to specific integration points), you can achieve this.

There aren't many offerings available in the market today that can do all of what you want in this domain. But, out of those, you should find WSO2 Governance Registry interesting. Please visit http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry.

Best Regards,
Senaka.

Comment: I've since looked at Galaxy, WSO2, and CentraSite CE.  All of these have the ability to track consumers; however, I found that CentraSite has the best inherent support for it.  From what I can tell, both Galaxy and WSO2 can support it through custom metadata and contacts respectively, but there are no features built around it.